# Simplify this expression that came from integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, special-functions

I was doing a calculation and arrived at a term $\left[P_{l-1}(\cos(\theta)) -P_{l+1}(\cos(\theta))\right]_{0}^{\pi}$(So this is the result of an integration). Does anybody of you know how to simplify this expression? (Testing suggested to me that this one is either $0$ or $2$, but I did not get there). $P_n$ is the $n$-th Legendre polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- Legendre polynomial $P_{l}(x)$ is either even (for even $l$) or odd (for odd $l$) function of $x$,
- Its value at $x=1$ is $P_l(1)=1$ (this is a part of its definition).

I think you can get the answer from there.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2(x-1)^{n-k}(x+1)^k$$ [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) for details. Your question asks for evaluating $$P_{l-1}(-1)-P_{l+1}(-1)-P_{l-1}(1)+P_{l+1}(1)$$ 
Now, easily we see $$P_n(1)=1,\ P_n(-1)=(-1)^n$$ So the expression evaluates to $$(-1)^{l-1}-(-1)^{l+1}-1+1=0$$